# How to make noWrap work with Breadcrumbs?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui, emotion

I'm trying to make the MUI component `Breadcrumbs` responsive:

When the `Breadcrumbs` component takes all of its space, its items shrink using ellipsis like any `Typography` component with `noWrap` prop set.

I know it has `itemsBeforeCollapse`, `itemsAfterCollapse` and `maxItems` props but these props are about item number compared to viewport size, not about each item width.

I tried to set the `noWrap` property to `Typography` and `Link` components (as it extends `Typography` props), but the ellipsis does not show up and the `Link` or `Typography` component does not shrink.

```
<Breadcrumbs>
  {links.map((link, i) =>
    i !== links.length - 1 ? (
      <Link
        key={i}
        underline={'hover'}
        noWrap
      >
        {link}
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <Typography noWrap key={i}>
        {link}
      </Typography>
    ),
  )}
</Breadcrumbs>
```

You can reproduce the issue on this codeSandbox:

[image: Edit BasicBreadcrumbs Material Demo (forked)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the `noWrap` style is not affecting the right element.

**Why?**

`noWrap` affect elements that its width limited either explicit (e.g. `width: 100px`) or implicit (by parent's width).

In your case, the `Link` and the `Typography`'s width is not limited.

**What can you do?**

`Breadcrumbs` renders `ol` with `display: flex`. In order to force the children (`li`) to stand a line (and take a third in your case) you should give it `flex: 1`. From this point, you can give the `li` the ellipsis styles.

The last part, how to give the `li` these styles? There are some ways as described at the [css](https://mui.com/api/breadcrumbs/#css) section.

I would take the `styled` approach and this is how it looks

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Breadcrumbs from "@mui/material/Breadcrumbs";
import Link from "@mui/material/Link";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledBreadcrumbs = styled(Breadcrumbs)`
  .MuiBreadcrumbs-li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex: 1;
  }
`;

export default function BasicBreadcrumbs() {
  const links = [
    "this is a waaaaaaaaaaaaay too long link",
    "and another link that can be long too",
    "this is the last link and guess what? It's waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyy more longer"
  ];
  return (
    <StyledBreadcrumbs>
      {links.map((link, i) =>
        i !== links.length - 1 ? (
          <Link key={i} underline={"hover"}>
            {link}
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <Typography key={i}>
            {link}
          </Typography>
        )
      )}
    </StyledBreadcrumbs>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/basicbreadcrumbs-material-demo-forked-y1bbo?file=/demo.js

Comment: I removed flex: 1, and add display:contents for parent element. had better result in my case.  .MuiBreadcrumbs-ol {display: contents;}

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Pay attention to `StyledBreadcrumbs` and `sx` inside the `<Breadcrumbs>`.

This shrinks all the items but the last one. If you want to shrink the last one, just remove `:not(:last-of-type)` in one of the style selectors.

```
import type { ReactElement } from 'react';
import type { BreadcrumbsProps } from '@mui/material';

import React, { MouseEventHandler } from 'react';
import { Link, Breadcrumbs as MUIBreadcrumbs, Typography, styled } from '@mui/material';

const StyledBreadcrumbs = styled(MUIBreadcrumbs)({
    maxWidth: '100%',
    '.MuiBreadcrumbs-ol': {
        flexWrap: 'nowrap'
    },
    '.MuiBreadcrumbs-separator': {
        flexShrink: 0
    },
    '.MuiBreadcrumbs-li:not(:last-of-type)': {
        overflow: 'hidden'
    }
});

export type Breadcrumb = {
    text: React.ReactNode;
    href?: string;
    onClick?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>;
};

type Props = {
    breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[];
} & Omit<BreadcrumbsProps, 'children'>;

export function Breadcrumbs({ breadcrumbs, ...props }: Props): ReactElement {
    return <StyledBreadcrumbs {...props}>
        {breadcrumbs.map(({ text, href, onClick }, index) => {

            const sx = index === breadcrumbs.length - 1 ? {} : {
                overflow: 'hidden',
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
            };

            if (href || onClick) {
                return (
                    <Link key={index} color='inherit' href={href} onClick={onClick} sx={sx}>
                        {text}
                    </Link>
                );
            }

            return (
                <Typography key={index} color='inherit' sx={sx}>
                    {text}
                </Typography>
            );
        })}
    </StyledBreadcrumbs>;
}
```